# Parsing Json and store data in sqlite database and view in a listView

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview

Hi all I am developing an app that collects data from a fake site rest bees and stores them in a listView. So far I managed to download the JSON file and display it in a listView. These are my classes:

HomeScreen.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
     private String classtag= HomeScreen.class.getSimpleName();  //return 
        name of underlying class
     private ListView lv;
     private ProgressDialog progress;
     private String url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; 
     //passing url
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> studentslist; //arraylist to save key 
     value pair from json
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
         studentslist=new ArrayList<>();
         lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); //from home screen listview
         new getStudents().execute(); // it will execute your AsyncTask
     } 
//--------------------------//-------------------------------//---------------------//
   public class getStudents extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute(); //it will use pre defined preExecute 
                                  method in async task
             progress=new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
             progress.setMessage("Fetching JSON.,."); // show what you want 
                                                      in the progress dialog
             progress.setCancelable(false); //progress dialog is not 
                                            cancellable here
            progress.show();
        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...arg0){
            HTTP_Handler hh = new HTTP_Handler(); // object of HTTP_Handler
            String jString = hh.makeHTTPCall(url); //calling makeHTTPCall 
                                  method and string its response in a string
            Log.e(classtag, "Response from URL: " + jString);
            if (jString != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray students = new JSONArray(jString);
                 //our json data starts with the object
                 //fetch array from studentsinfo object
                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = students.getJSONObject(i); //get object 
                                                                from i index
                    String userId=obj.getString("userId");   //save string 
                                            from variable 'id' to string
                    String id=obj.getString("id");
                    String title=obj.getString("title");
                    String body=obj.getString("body");
                    HashMap<String, String> studentdata = new HashMap<>(); 
                      //create a hash map to set key and value pair

                    studentdata.put("userId", userId); //hash map will save 
                                                    key and its value
                    studentdata.put("id", id);
                    studentdata.put("title", title);
                    studentdata.put("body", body);

                    studentslist.add(studentdata); //now save all of the key 
                                                    value pairs to arraylist
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(classtag, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show(); //show if you catch any exception 
                                                                 with data
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(classtag, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check internet 
                                                    connection!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//show if you are unable 
                        to connect with the internet or if jString is null
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Result){
        super.onPostExecute(Result);
        if(progress.isShowing()){
            progress.dismiss();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(
                HomeScreen.this,
                studentslist,
                R.layout.bucket_list,
                new String[]{"userId","id","title","body"},
                new int[]{R.id.list_Name,R.id.list_Email,R.id.list_Address 
                                                       ,R.id.list_Gender});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

Http_Handler.java

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HTTP_Handler {
      private static final String classtag= 
      HTTP_Handler.class.getSimpleName();  //return name of underlying class

public String makeHTTPCall(String URLinput) { // method which will request 
               to server when provided with url
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLinput);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                //to open connection with url
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");   //request type is of GET, which 
                           means to get information from the server

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
         //storing the input stream we are getting for the url
        response = InputStreamToString(in); //now storing string from the 
                                            input stream
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(classtag, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(classtag, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(classtag, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(classtag, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response; //returning whatever we fetching from the string to the 
                     method.
  }
private String InputStreamToString(InputStream is) {   //fetching string 
    form the input stream
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); //it 
    will read form stream
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n'); //whatever we read from the 
            stream, we will append it to the stringbuilder
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to integrate the saving in SQLite database and display ever in a listView.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you read online documentation and tutorials about how to connect with a SQLite database? What specific problems you encountered?

Comment: I want a complete picture of coming to proceed, because I am a beginner.

Comment: Then you should definitely read the Android documentation at http://developer.android.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links:

Json Parsing:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Database:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

These will give you a good idea on how to approach these things.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for best practices of what to do next and you don't want to read a complete Code Apprentice then read the basics about this. Hope it helps

1. Java Beans (getter and setters)
2. GSon or any other tool to convert from JSON to objects and viceversa
3. How to store/retrieve your object to/from SQLite with one SQL connection
4. Recycler View
5. Holder pattern

Your question is too wide. Once you start properly with your code, keep asking.